# How to plot a correlation matrix into a graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, correlation

I have a matrix with some correlation values. Now I want to plot that in a graph that looks more or less like that:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Quick, dirty, and in the ballpark:

```
library(lattice)

#Build the horizontal and vertical axis information
hor <- c("214", "215", "216", "224", "211", "212", "213", "223", "226", "225")
ver <- paste("DM1-", hor, sep="")

#Build the fake correlation matrix
nrowcol <- length(ver)
cor <- matrix(runif(nrowcol*nrowcol, min=0.4), nrow=nrowcol, ncol=nrowcol, dimnames = list(hor, ver))
for (i in 1:nrowcol) cor[i,i] = 1

#Build the plot
rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow"), space = "rgb")
levelplot(cor, main="stage 12-14 array correlation matrix", xlab="", ylab="", col.regions=rgb.palette(120), cuts=100, at=seq(0,1,0.01))
```

[image]

Comment: It looks very similar to example from OP (fonts, colors, layout). Looks like original was created with lattice too. Great detailed answer, +1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Many people are used to correlation plots in which the diagonal containing 1-s runs from the top left to the bottom right square (see the example figure in the question), rather than from the bottom left to the top right square, as in your solution. Here's how to fix this problem:
cor_reversed <- apply(cor, 2, rev);
levelplot(t(cor_reversed),...)

Comment: @bill_080 why copy-pasting your code wont print the correlation matrix?

Comment: @Pavlos   When I copy/paste the code, it provides the same basic chart above.

Answer (score 61):

Rather "less" look like, but worth checking (as giving more visual information):

[Correlation matrix ellipses](http://www.improving-visualisation.org/vis/id=250):
[image: Correlation matrix ellipses]
[Correlation matrix circles](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Correlation_matrix_circles,152):
[image: Correlation matrix circles]

Please find more examples in the [corrplot vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) referenced by @assylias below.

Comment: The site seems to be defunct. Do you have any code or package description for the first plot?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander: As far as I remember, the first plot was created by `ellipse:plotcorr`.

Comment: I've submitted an edit for link 1 to: http://www.improving-visualisation.org/vis/id=250 which provides the same image.

Comment: Thank you @rpierce, although I see only the image there without the R source. What do I miss here?

Comment: @daroczig https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html

Answer (score 43):

Very easy with lattice::levelplot:

```
z <- cor(mtcars)
require(lattice)
levelplot(z)
```

[image]

Answer (score 31):

The ggplot2 library can handle this with `geom_tile()`. It looks like there may have been some rescaling done in that plot above as there aren't any negative correlations, so take that into consideration with your data. Using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

z <- cor(mtcars)
z.m <- melt(z)

ggplot(z.m, aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue",  high = "yellow")
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

```
ggplot(z.m, aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue",  high = "yellow")
```

[image]

allows to specify the colour of the midpoint and it defaults to white so may be a nice adjustment here. Other options can be found on the ggplot website [here](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_gradient2.html) and [here](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_gradientn.html).

Comment: nice (+1)! Though I would add a manual-break scale (e.g: `c(-1, -0.6, -0.3, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 1)`) with `"white"` in the middle to let the colors reflect the symmetry of the correlation efficient.

Comment: @Daroczig - Good point. It looks like `scale_fill_gradient2()` achieves the functionality you describe automatically. I didn't know that existed.

Comment: adding to this: `p <- ggplot(.....) + ... + ....; library(plotly); ggplotly(p)` will make it interactive

Comment: To make the diagonal 1's go from top left to bottom right, reversal of factor levels is required for `X1` using: `z.m$X1 <- factor(z.m$X1, levels = rev(levels( z.m$X1 )))`

Answer (score 12):

Use the corrplot package:

```
library(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)
##  different color series
col1 <- colorRampPalette(c("#7F0000","red","#FF7F00","yellow","white", 
        "cyan", "#007FFF", "blue","#00007F"))
col2 <- colorRampPalette(c("#67001F", "#B2182B", "#D6604D", "#F4A582", "#FDDBC7",
        "#FFFFFF", "#D1E5F0", "#92C5DE", "#4393C3", "#2166AC", "#053061"))  
col3 <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "white", "blue")) 
col4 <- colorRampPalette(c("#7F0000","red","#FF7F00","yellow","#7FFF7F", 
        "cyan", "#007FFF", "blue","#00007F"))   
wb <- c("white","black")


par(ask = TRUE)


## different color scale and methods to display corr-matrix
corrplot(M, method="number", col="black", addcolorlabel="no")
corrplot(M, method="number")
corrplot(M)
corrplot(M, order ="AOE")
corrplot(M, order ="AOE", addCoef.col="grey")

corrplot(M, order="AOE", col=col1(20), cl.length=21,addCoef.col="grey")
corrplot(M, order="AOE", col=col1(10),addCoef.col="grey")

corrplot(M, order="AOE", col=col2(200))
corrplot(M, order="AOE", col=col2(200),addCoef.col="grey")
corrplot(M, order="AOE", col=col2(20), cl.length=21,addCoef.col="grey")
corrplot(M, order="AOE", col=col2(10),addCoef.col="grey")

corrplot(M, order="AOE", col=col3(100))
corrplot(M, order="AOE", col=col3(10))



corrplot(M, method="color", col=col1(20), cl.length=21,order = "AOE", addCoef.col="grey")

if(TRUE){

corrplot(M, method="square", col=col2(200),order = "AOE")

corrplot(M, method="ellipse", col=col1(200),order = "AOE")


corrplot(M, method="shade", col=col3(20),order = "AOE")

corrplot(M, method="pie", order = "AOE")


## col=wb
corrplot(M, col = wb, order="AOE", outline=TRUE, addcolorlabel="no")
## like Chinese wiqi, suit for either on screen or white-black print.
corrplot(M, col = wb, bg="gold2",  order="AOE", addcolorlabel="no")
}
```

For example:

[image]

Rather elegant IMO

Answer (score 9):

That type of graph is called a "heat map" among other terms.  Once you've got your correlation matrix, plot it using one of the various tutorials out there.

Using base graphics:
http://flowingdata.com/2010/01/21/how-to-make-a-heatmap-a-quick-and-easy-solution/

Using ggplot2:
http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/

Comment: I'm not sure if calling it a 'heatmap' is a fairly modern invention. It seems to make sense if you are trying to show 'hotspots' by using a red-orange-yellow colour scheme, but in general its just an image plot, or a matrix plot, or a raster plot. I'll be interested to find the oldest reference that calls it a 'heatmap'. tldr; "[citation needed]"

Comment: I think you're right that heat map isn't necessarily the earliest name for it.  Wikipedia lists a 1957 paper, but I checked that paper and the term "heat map" appears nowhere in it (nor do the graphics look exactly like the current form).

Answer (score 5):

I have been working on something similar to the visualization posted by @daroczig, with code posted by @Ulrik using the `plotcorr()` function of the `ellipse` package.  I like the use of ellipses to represent correlations, and the use of colors to represent negative and positive correlation.  However, I wanted the eye-catching colors to stand out for correlations close to 1 and -1, not for those close to 0.

I created an alternative in which white ellipses are overlaid on colored circles.  Each white ellipse is sized so that the proportion of the colored circle visible behind it is equal to the squared correlation.  When the correlation is near 1 and -1, the white ellipse is small, and much of the colored circle is visible.  When the correlation is near 0, the white ellipse is large, and little of the colored circle is visible.

The function, `plotcor()`, is available at https://github.com/JVAdams/jvamisc/blob/master/R/plotcor.r.

An example of the resulting plot using the `mtcars` dataset is shown below.

```
library(plotrix)
library(seriation)
library(MASS)
plotcor(cor(mtcars), mar=c(0.1, 4, 4, 0.1))
```

[image: result of call to plotcor() function]

Answer (score 3):

The **corrplot()** function from **corrplot R package** can be also used to plot a correlogram.

```
library(corrplot)  
M<-cor(mtcars) # compute correlation matrix
corrplot(M, method="circle")
```

several articles describing how to compute and visualize correlation matrix are published here:

- http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/visualize-correlation-matrix-using-correlogram
- http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/visualize-correlation-matrix-using-symnum-function

Answer (score 3):

I realise that it's been a while, but new readers might be interested in `rplot()` from the `corrr` package (https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/corrr/index.html), which can produce the sorts of plots @daroczig mentions, but design for a data pipeline approach:

```
install.packages("corrr")
library(corrr)
mtcars %>% correlate() %>% rplot()
```

[image]

```
mtcars %>% correlate() %>% rearrange() %>% rplot()
```

[image]

```
mtcars %>% correlate() %>% rearrange() %>% rplot(shape = 15)
```

[image]

```
mtcars %>% correlate() %>% rearrange() %>% shave() %>% rplot(shape = 15)
```

[image]

```
mtcars %>% correlate() %>% rearrange(absolute = FALSE) %>% rplot(shape = 15)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I recently learned about is an interactive heatmap created with the **qtlcharts** package.

```
install.packages("qtlcharts")
library(qtlcharts)
iplotCorr(mat=mtcars, group=mtcars$cyl, reorder=TRUE)
```

Below is a static image of the resulting plot.
[image]

You can see the interactive version on [my blog](http://adamistics.blogspot.com/2016/03/interactive-heatmap-of-correlation.html#links).  Hover over the heatmap to see the row, column, and cell values. Click on a cell to see a scatterplot with symbols colored by group (in this example, the number of cylinders, 4 is red, 6 is green, and 8 is blue).  Hovering over the points in the scatterplot gives the name of the row (in this case the make of the car).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the [GGally](https://r-graph-gallery.com/199-correlation-matrix-with-ggally.html) package with [ggcorr](https://briatte.github.io/ggcorr/) function like this:

```r
library(GGally)
ggcorr(mtcars, method = c("everything", "pearson"), label = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
ggcorr(mtcars, method = c("everything", "pearson"), label = TRUE, geom = "circle")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Check the links above for a lot of more options.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment, I have to give my 2c to the answer by daroczig as an anwser...

The ellipse scatter plot is indeed from the ellipse package and generated with:

```
corr.mtcars <- cor(mtcars)
ord <- order(corr.mtcars[1,])
xc <- corr.mtcars[ord, ord]
colors <- c("#A50F15","#DE2D26","#FB6A4A","#FCAE91","#FEE5D9","white",
            "#EFF3FF","#BDD7E7","#6BAED6","#3182BD","#08519C")   
plotcorr(xc, col=colors[5*xc + 6])
```

(from the man page)

The corrplot package may also - as suggested - be useful with pretty images [found here](http://weitaiyun.blogspot.de/2011/12/some-example-graphs-in-corrplot-060_08.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a textbook example for a hierarchical clustering heatmap (with dendrogram). Using `gplots` `heatmap.2` because it's superior to the base heatmap, but the idea is the same. `colorRampPalette` helps generating 50 (transitional) colors.

```
library(gplots)

heatmap.2(cor(mtcars), trace="none", col=colorRampPalette(c("blue2","white","red3"))(50))
```

[image: heatmap.2 correlation values blue white red]