# Simple Markov Chain in R (visualization)

Tags: r, statistics, visualization, markov

i'd like to do a simple first order markov chain in R. I know there are packages like MCMC, but couldn't found one to display it graphically. Is this even possible? It would be nice if given a transition matrix and an initial state, one can visually see the path through the markov chain (maybe i've to do this by hand...).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the packages in this area, but if you can't find a canned plotting command you like, you can always extract the matrices yourself and plot them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453336/r-plot-correlation-matrix-into-a-graph

Comment: thanks. that would be another idea in case there dosen't exist anything like that :).

Comment: a little more clarification or a crude example of what you want would be helpful: the answers below are all over the map because people are interpreted your question in different ways.

Answer (score 10):

This shows how to apply a random transition matrix to a particular starting vector: c(1,0,0,0):

```
set.seed(123)
tmat <- matrix(rnorm(16)^2,ncol=4) 
   # need entries to be positive, could have used abs()
tmat <- tmat/rowSums(tmat) # need the rows to sum to 1
tmat
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,] 0.326123580 0.01735335 0.48977444 0.166748625
[2,] 0.016529424 0.91768404 0.06196453 0.003822008
[3,] 0.546050789 0.04774713 0.33676288 0.069439199
[4,] 0.001008839 0.32476060 0.02627217 0.647958394
require(expm)   # for the %^% function
matplot( t(         # need to transpose to get arguments to matplot correctly
       sapply(1:20, function(x) matrix(c(1,0,0,0), ncol=4) %*% (tmat %^% x) ) ) )
```

You can see it approaching equilibrium:
[image]

Comment: I get `Error: unexpected '[' in "            ["
Execution halted
`

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. The code still runs with exactly that output in R 3.1.2

Comment: Hmm... seems to work in Rstudio (although it also prints `Error: unexpected '[' in "["`), but not when I execute it as Rscript via bash. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: None at all. Seems like you have a good question for the RStudio Q&Q webpage.

Answer (score 4):

The package coda (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coda/index.html) has tools for analyzing MCMC results, including some plotting functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You can use markovchain R package, that models Discrete Time Markov Chains and contains a plotting facility based on igraph package.

```
library(markovchain) #loading the package
myMatr<-matrix(c(0,.2,.8,.1,.8,.1,.3,0,.7),byrow=TRUE,nrow = 3) #defining a transition matrix
rownames(myMatr)<-colnames(myMatr)<-c("a","b","c")
myMc<-as(myMatr, "markovchain")
plot(myMc)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this query on Biostar can help you: [Visualizing HMM files of HMMER3](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/visualizing-hmm-files-of-hmmer3). It point to two external applications, [LogoMat-M](http://www.sanger.ac.uk/cgi-bin/software/analysis/logomat-m.cgi) and [HMMeditor](http://casp.rnet.missouri.edu/hmmeditor/), for visualizing Profile Hidden Markov Models (pHMMs).