# How can I create a correlation matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, visualization, correlation

I have 92 set of data of same type.

I want to make a correlation matrix for any two combinations possible.

i.e., I want a matrix of `92x92`.

such that element (`ci`,`cj`) should be correlation between `ci` and `cj`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Have a look to the `cor` function, or to the `rcorr` function in the `Hmisc` package

Comment: I'm able to find the cor between two parameters. The thing is how to arrange them in matrix?

Comment: How on Earth did this get so many upvotes?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

An example,

```
 d <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(10),
                 x2=rnorm(10),
                 x3=rnorm(10))
cor(d) # get correlations (returns matrix)
```

Answer (score 76):

You could use 'corrplot' package.

```
d <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(10),
                 x2=rnorm(10),
                 x3=rnorm(10))
M <- cor(d) # get correlations

library('corrplot') #package corrplot
corrplot(M, method = "circle") #plot matrix
```

[image]

More information here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the graph similar to these ones http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html, or a simple matrix, but with the R-squared instead of pearson, kendall, or spearman correlation?

Comment: R2 equals the square of the Pearson correlation coefficient. So all you need is multiply M by M (multiply correlation matrix by itself), before creating the plot.

Answer (score 18):

The *cor* function will use the columns of the matrix in the calculation of correlation. So, the number of rows must be the same between your matrix *x* and matrix *y*. Ex.:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=5, ncol=4)
y <- matrix(rnorm(15), nrow=5, ncol=3)
COR <- cor(x,y)
COR
image(x=seq(dim(x)[2]), y=seq(dim(y)[2]), z=COR, xlab="x column", ylab="y column")
text(expand.grid(x=seq(dim(x)[2]), y=seq(dim(y)[2])), labels=round(c(COR),2))
```

[image]

#### Edit:

Here is an example of custom row and column labels on a correlation matrix calculated with a single matrix:

```
png("corplot.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", res=200)
op <- par(mar=c(6,6,1,1), ps=10)
COR <- cor(iris[,1:4])
image(x=seq(nrow(COR)), y=seq(ncol(COR)), z=cor(iris[,1:4]), axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")
text(expand.grid(x=seq(dim(COR)[1]), y=seq(dim(COR)[2])), labels=round(c(COR),2))
box()
axis(1, at=seq(nrow(COR)), labels = rownames(COR), las=2)
axis(2, at=seq(ncol(COR)), labels = colnames(COR), las=1)
par(op)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: @Manuel Ramón 's example is probably best for your case (a single matrix) - organize your data sets as columns.

Comment: in the image above, how can one 'invert' the colors, the is red one correlation is close to -1 or 1 and white when close to 0?

Comment: `image(x=seq(dim(x)[2]), y=seq(dim(y)[2]), z=COR, col=rev(heat.colors(20)), xlab="x column", ylab="y column")`

Comment: @Marcinthebox how would you add variable labels to x and y axis (instead of numbers)? Thanks

Comment: @AgustínIndaco - I have updated my answer with a further example. The `image` function doesn't automatically take the row and column names, so this must be added.

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at [qtlcharts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qtlcharts/index.html). It allows you to create **interactive** correlation matrices:

```
library(qtlcharts)
data(iris)
iris$Species <- NULL
iplotCorr(iris, reorder=TRUE)
```

[image]

It's more impressive when you correlate more variables, like in the package's vignette:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways to achieve this here: ([Plot correlation matrix into a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453336/plot-correlation-matrix-into-a-graph#5454100)), but I like your version with the correlations in the boxes. Is there a way to add the variable names to the x and y column instead of just those index numbers? For me, that would make this a perfect solution. Thanks!

edit: I was trying to comment on the post by [Marc in the box], but I clearly don't know what I'm doing. However, I did manage to answer this question for myself.

if d is the matrix (or the original data frame) and the column names are what you want, then the following works:

```
axis(1, 1:dim(d)[2], colnames(d), las=2)
axis(2, 1:dim(d)[2], colnames(d), las=2)
```

las=0 would flip the names back to their normal position, mine were long, so I used las=2 to make them perpendicular to the axis.

edit2: to suppress the image() function printing numbers on the grid (otherwise they overlap your variable labels), add xaxt='n', e.g.:

```
image(x=seq(dim(x)[2]), y=seq(dim(y)[2]), z=COR, col=rev(heat.colors(20)), xlab="x column", ylab="y column", xaxt='n')
```