# How to calculate correlation coefficient with R?

Tags: excel, r, correlation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [correlation matrix in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680658/correlation-matrix-in-r)

I  have an excel sheet  which  has 700 columns and 25 rows. The sample of my file is shown   below. I would like to calculate the correlation coefficient between  A1 and A700, A2 and A700, A3 and A700 ,A4 and A700  and so on. What is the easiest way to do this with R?

```
       A1     A2     A3     A4   ---- --- A700

 A    2.7     5       4     34             34
 B    5.67   7.8      6     45            25.6
 C    2.3    -9      12.5   13            2.8
 D    5.6    6       -56    2.5          -66.7
 E    7.8    5       20     6.7          -56.8 
--
--
--
--
```

Comment: 1) Did you mean 700 Rows and 25 Columns? 2) If you are doing this in Excel, did you check out the `=CORREL()`?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Did you understand my question? I don't want to create a matrix. I need to print the correlation coefficients only. Dear friend, please check my accepted answer. I think, this is not a duplicate question. In my case, the number of rows and columns are not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
table <- read.xls(file)
x <- table[1:699]
y <- table[700]
cor(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your perfect answer. I think, you only understood my question clearly.

Comment: to be honest, it was a Google search away

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `?cor`.

For example:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)
cor(m)
```

Gives you all the correlations.