# Chi-square p value matrix in r

Tags: r, chi-squared

Is there any way to find the chi-square p-value matrix in 'R' (a matrix with the p-values between the attributes)?

As an example, consider the the `iris` data set. I am looking for a matrix as follows:

```
|                | Sepal length | Sepal width | Petal length | Petal width | Species |
|----------------|--------------|-------------|--------------|-------------|---------| 
| Sepal length   |              |             |              |             |         |
| Sepal width    |              |             |              |             |         |
| Petal length   |              |             |              |             |         |
| Petal width    |              |             |              |             |         |
| Species        |              |             |              |             |         |
```

The elements of the matrix would be the chi square values for the (i,j) variables of the `iris` data set.

Comment: Could you show your expected output?

Comment: Sepal length    Sepal width    Petal length   Petal width   Species

Sepal length

Sepal width

Petal length

Petal width

Species

Comment: p values should be between the attributes, rows and cols are attributes names

Comment: it would be clearer if you edited your question with those informations and formatted this output as a matrix

Comment: They are all continuous variables and how can you do chi squared test? You can do a matrix of correlation p values.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain matrix of correlation p values?

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680658/how-can-i-create-a-correlation-matrix-in-r) (2nd Google hit for 'correlation matrix in r')

Answer (score 8):

If that is what you want considering only one of those columns is a categorical variable, Try this:

```
chisqmatrix <- function(x) {
  names = colnames(x);  num = length(names)
  m = matrix(nrow=num,ncol=num,dimnames=list(names,names))
  for (i in 1:(num-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):num) {
      m[i,j] = chisq.test(x[,i],x[,j],)$p.value
    }
  }
  return (m)
}
mat = chisqmatrix(iris)
```

Comment: If the data is a tibble, use `chisq.test(pull(x, i), pull(x, j))$p.value`