# Create a corrplot from continuous and discrete column values using R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, r-corrplot

I believe the issue is in using three columns to create the correlation matrix. I attempted to follow the suggestions in this post: [How can I create a correlation matrix in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680658/how-can-i-create-a-correlation-matrix-in-r) , but to no avail.

Furthermore, running the "rd_sample <- reading_data..." block gives the error "could not find function 'reading_data'". However, running "class(reading_data)" confirms it is a dataframe.

```
##corrplot
install.packages("corrplot")

rd_sample <- reading_data(live1 = rnorm(10),   #live1 values are discrete
                          reg = rnorm(10),     #reg values are discrete 
                          books1 = rnorm(10))  #books1 values are continuous 

M <- cor(rd_sample) # get correlations (returns matrix)

library(corrplot)
corrplot(M)
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being familiar with the function `reading_data`, I simply created a data frame and then used your code with the defaults for `corrplot`.

```
rd_sample <- data.frame(live1 = rnorm(10),   #live1 values are discrete
                          reg = rnorm(10),     #reg values are discrete 
                          books1 = rnorm(10))

M <- cor(rd_sample) # get correlations (returns matrix)

library(corrplot)
corrplot(M)
```

[image]