# How to correlate and visualise correlation of one variable versus many

Tags: r

I want to use R to visualise and calculate the correlation of one variable data[1] to many other variables data[2:96]

I am already aware of what packages such as psych and PerformanceAnalytics have the Pairs function.

Ideally, I would like to output a graph like that Pairs outputs, but only for the correlations between data[1] and each of data[2:96], not for each of the elements of data[1:96] with itself, that would take up too much space. Any ideas on this would be appreciated.

Comment: This post might give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453336/plot-correlation-matrix-into-a-graph

Comment: Thanks, although most of those are nxn again, while I am looking for 1xn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also retrieve subsets of the correlation matrix to solve this. For example, `cor(data)[,1]` gives the correlations between column 1 and all the others.

Answer (score 9):

Can use the `corrr` package to `focus()` on your variable of choice, then `ggplot2` package to plot the results. For example, get/plot correlations of `mpg` with all other variables in the `mtcars` data set:

```
library(corrr)
library(ggplot2)

x <- mtcars %>% 
  correlate() %>% 
  focus(mpg)
x
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    rowname        mpg
#>      <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1      cyl -0.8521620
#> 2     disp -0.8475514
#> 3       hp -0.7761684
#> 4     drat  0.6811719
#> 5       wt -0.8676594
#> 6     qsec  0.4186840
#> 7       vs  0.6640389
#> 8       am  0.5998324
#> 9     gear  0.4802848
#> 10    carb -0.5509251

x %>% 
  mutate(rowname = factor(rowname, levels = rowname[order(mpg)])) %>%  # Order by correlation strength
  ggplot(aes(x = rowname, y = mpg)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    ylab("Correlation with mpg") +
    xlab("Variable")
```

[image]

Comment: I want to color the bars that are significant to 0.05 level. This is possible using `mutate(p_val = round(2*pt(-abs(mpg*sqrt((32-2)/(1-mpg^2))), 32-2),2))`  to create a column with the p-values. then I can create a binary character column using `mutate(sig = ifelse(p_val <= 0.05, 'sig', 'not')`. Is there a cleaner way to add this third column with the p-values to the dataframe `x` using `corrr` or `cor.test()$p.value`?

Answer (score 4):

Using `mtcars` data and the `corrplot{}` package:

```
install.packages("corrplot")
library(corrplot)
mcor <- cor(x = mtcars$mpg, y = mtcars[2:11], use="complete.obs")
corrplot(mcor, tl.srt = 25)
```

Edit: Forgot to put in a vignette for `corrplot` showing more ways to format it: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To get the scatter plots with loess lines, you can combine the `tidyr` package with `ggplot2`. Here's an example of the scatter plots of `mpg` with all other variables in the `mtcars` data set:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
  gather(-mpg, key = "var", value = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = mpg)) +
    facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free") +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth()
```

[image]

For more details on how this works, see https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/quick-plot-of-all-variables