# How to Add Labels to Top X-Axis of Levelplot in Lattice Package

Tags: r, matrix, plot, lattice, levelplot

So I'm making correlation-matrix-like plots using levelplot similar to this (taken from: [Plot correlation matrix into a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453336/plot-correlation-matrix-into-a-graph)):

```
library(lattice)

#Build the horizontal and vertical axis information
hor <- c("214", "215", "216", "224", "211", "212", "213", "223", "226", "225")
ver <- paste("DM1-", hor, sep="")

#Build the fake correlation matrix
nrowcol <- length(ver)
cor <- matrix(runif(nrowcol*nrowcol, min=0.4), nrow=nrowcol, ncol=nrowcol, dimnames = list(hor, ver))
for (i in 1:nrowcol) cor[i,i] = 1

#Build the plot
rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow"), space = "rgb")
levelplot(cor, main="stage 12-14 array correlation matrix", xlab="", ylab="", col.regions=rgb.palette(120), cuts=100, at=seq(0,1,0.01))
```

I would like to add labels to each of the top (second) x-axis ticks. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thank you,

Kai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by adding `scales=list(alternating=3)` to your call of `levelplot`

If you look up the help for `levelplot`, for some information, you are referred to `xyplot` (and others).  It is in the `xyplot` help page, you find a description of `scales` and therein `alternating`. Alternating controls the location of the tick labels and can take 4 values:

- `0` (none),
- `1` (bottom/left),
- `2` (top/right),
- `3` (both).

Here is the call to levelplot that gives you ticks at all sides:

```
levelplot(cor, main="stage 12-14 array correlation matrix", xlab="", ylab="", col.regions=rgb.palette(120), cuts=100, at=seq(0,1,0.01), scales=list(alternating=3))
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution duplicated my primary x-axis on the secondary x-axis.

I would actually like to display a different set of labels on the secondary x-axis. Is this possible?

Comment: @foxandsticks My pleasure! Regarding your latest question, I have to investigate this, and I don't have time today. I suggest you **open a new question**, with data and code, and with a description what you already discovered/solved (like the above). This way, you may attract attention from other people. I will upvote your new question when I see it passing. Good Luck!

Comment: Many thanks @KoenV! A new questions has been posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526149/add-different-labels-to-secondary-x-axis-of-levelplot-in-lattice-in-r