# Calculate pairwise spearman's rank correlation from data present in all files in a directory

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, bioinformatics

I'm trying to calculate Spearman's rank correlation, where the data (tsv with name and rank) for each experiment is stored in separate files in a directory.

Following is the format of input files:

```
#header not present
#geneName   value
ENSMUSG00000026179.14   14.5648627685587
ENSMUSG00000026179.14   0.652158034413075
ENSMUSG00000026179.14   0.652158034413075
ENSMUSG00000026179.14   1.852158034413075
ENSMUSG00000026176.13   4.13033421794948
ENSMUSG00000026176.13   4.13033421794948
ENSMUSG00000026176.13   15.4344068144428
ENSMUSG00000026176.13   15.4344068144428
ENSMUSG00000026176.13   6.9563523670728
...
```

My problem is that the keys(gene names) are repetitive, and each experiment file contains different but overlapping set of gene names. What I need is an intersection of gene names for each pair while performing the correlation and removing duplicates, probably something like this pseudo code:

```
# Find correlation for all possible pairs of input(i.e. files in directory)
files = list_Of_files("directory")
for(i in files) {
    for(k in files) {
    CommonGenes <- intersect (i,k)
    tempi <- removeRepetitive(i, CommonGenes) #Keep the gene with highest value and remove all other repeating genes. Also, keep only common genes.
    tempk <- removeRepetitive(k, CommonGenes) #Keep the gene with highest value and remove all other repeating genes. Also, keep only common genes. 
    correlationArray[] <- spearman(tempi, tempk) #Perform correlation for only the common genes
}
}
```

Ultimately, I want to plot the correlation matrix using *corrplot* or *qtlcharts*.

Comment: Your for loop does not look like an R code.

Comment: @ycw, I'm sorry. I usually work with python, so I find writing dummy examples in python "like" format easier. I will update my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read all the data into a list of dataframes, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432) for more info, here we are just creating a dummy data.

```
library(dplyr)

# dummy data
set.seed(1)
myDfs <- list(
  data.frame(geneName = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 15, replace = TRUE), value = runif(15)),
  data.frame(geneName = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 15, replace = TRUE), value = runif(15)),
  data.frame(geneName = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 15, replace = TRUE), value = runif(15)),
  data.frame(geneName = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 15, replace = TRUE), value = runif(15)),
  data.frame(geneName = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 15, replace = TRUE), value = runif(15))
)
```

Then, just like your two nested *for* loops, what we have here is two nested *apply* functions. Within loops we are aggregating and getting correlation on matched *merged* genes names.

```
res <- sapply(myDfs, function(i){
  # group by gene, get max value
  imax <- i %>% group_by(geneName) %>% summarise(i_Max = max(value))
  sapply(myDfs, function(j){
    # group by gene, get max value
    jmax <- j %>% group_by(geneName) %>% summarise(j_Max = max(value))
    # get overlapping genes
    ij <- merge(imax, jmax, by = "geneName")
    # return correlation
    cor(ij$i_Max, ij$j_Max, method = "spearman")
  })
})
```

`res` will have the correlation matrix.

```
res

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]  1.0 -0.2  1.0  0.4 -0.4
# [2,] -0.2  1.0 -0.2  0.8  0.0
# [3,]  1.0 -0.2  1.0  0.4 -0.4
# [4,]  0.4  0.8  0.4  1.0 -0.4
# [5,] -0.4  0.0 -0.4 -0.4  1.0
```

For correlation plot there are [many alternatives to choose from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453336). Here as an example we are using *corrplot*:

```
corrplot::corrplot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I encountered another problem. The solution works, but I cannot define the labels based on file names. The current method disregards any sort of labels all together, but keeps the order of dataframes. I can use that information to label the rows and columns manually, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it automatically ?

Comment: @Siddharth avoid asking new questions, I think you have already answered your own question anyway. Yes, keeps the order, you could add manually to the plot, or give a named object to corrplot.

Comment: sorry for that! I managed to that and modified the code to generate scatter-plot for each pair. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an alternative solution. Rather than having a nested loop, it uses `expand.grid` to create the combinations, and then uses a pipeline of ‹dplyr› verbs to calculate correlations on a subset of the master table.

This approach has both advantages and disadvantages. Foremost it fits nicely into the “tidy data” approach, and [there are some who advocate to work in tidy data as much as possible](http://varianceexplained.org/r/tidy-genomics-biobroom/). The actual code is about as long as zx8754’s.

```
library(dplyr)

genes = sprintf('ENSMUSG%011d', 1 : 50)
my_dfs = replicate(4, tibble(Gene = sample(genes, 20, replace = TRUE), Value = runif(20)),
                   simplify = FALSE)
```

First off we want to make the gene names unique because everything subsequently requires unique genes per table:

```
my_dfs = lapply(my_dfs, function (x) summarize(group_by(x, Gene), Value = max(Value)))
```

Now we can create all permutations of this list:

```
combinations = bind_cols(expand.grid(i = seq_along(my_dfs), j = seq_along(my_dfs)),
                         expand.grid(x = my_dfs, y = my_dfs))
```

At this point, we have a table with the indices of all pairwise combinations *i*, *j*, as well as the combinations themselves as list columns:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
       i     j                 x                 y
   <int> <int>            <list>            <list>
 1     1     1 <tibble [17 x 2]> <tibble [17 x 2]>
 2     2     1 <tibble [18 x 2]> <tibble [17 x 2]>
 3     3     1 <tibble [19 x 2]> <tibble [17 x 2]>
…
```

We now group by the indices and join the single list columns in each group by gene names:

```
correlations = combinations %>%
    group_by(i, j) %>%
    do(inner_join(.$x[[1]], .$y[[1]], by = 'Gene')) %>%
    print() %>%
    summarize(Cor = cor(Value.x, Value.y, method = 'spearman'))
```

Intermission: at the `print()` line we are left with a fully-expanded table of all pairwise combinations of all gene tables (the `Value` columns of the two original tables have been renamed into `Value.x` and `Value.y`, respectively):

```
# A tibble: 182 x 5
# Groups:   i, j [16]
       i     j               Gene    Value.x    Value.y
   <int> <int>              <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1     1 ENSMUSG00000000014 0.93470523 0.93470523
 2     1     1 ENSMUSG00000000019 0.21214252 0.21214252
 3     1     1 ENSMUSG00000000028 0.65167377 0.65167377
 4     1     1 ENSMUSG00000000043 0.12555510 0.12555510
 5     1     1 ENSMUSG00000000010 0.26722067 0.26722067
 6     1     1 ENSMUSG00000000041 0.38611409 0.38611409
 7     1     1 ENSMUSG00000000042 0.01339033 0.01339033
…
```

The next line trivially calculates pairwise correlations from these tables, using the same groups. Since the whole table is in long format, it can be conveniently plotted with ‹ggplot2›:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(correlations) +
    aes(i, j, color = Cor) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_color_gradient2()
```

[image]

… but if you need this as a square correlation matrix instead, nothing is easier:

```
corr_mat = with(correlations, matrix(Cor, nrow = max(i)))
```

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  1.00  1.00 -0.20 -0.26
[2,]  1.00  1.00 -0.43 -0.50
[3,] -0.20 -0.43  1.00 -0.90
[4,] -0.26 -0.50 -0.90  1.00
```